# Unable to resolve x imports

Tags: square-wire

I am getting (using: api 'com.squareup.wire:wire-runtime:3.0.2')

```
Execution failed for task ':app:generateProtos'.
unable to resolve 1 imports: testing/tastes/tastes.proto
searching 0 proto paths:
```

My understanding is that I do not need to define anything in gradle for looking for imports?

But when it says `searching 0 proto paths`, it makes me wonder....

My gradle is:

`wire { kotlin { android = true } }`

File Structure is

```
      -> proto
           -> testing
                -> people
                     -> person.proto
                -> tastes
                     -> tastes.proto
```

my import line in `person.proto` is: `import "testing/tastes/tastes.proto";`

```
syntax = "proto2";
package testing.people;
option java_package = "com.testing.people";

import "testing/tastes/tastes.proto";

message WirePerson {

    optional string name = 1;
    repeated string picture_urls = 2;
    optional testing.tastes.WirePersonTaste period = 5;
}
```

```
syntax = "proto2";
package testing.tastes;
option java_package = "com.testing.tastes";

message WirePersonTaste {
    optional string taste = 1;
    repeated string picture_urls = 2;
}
```

I would be very grateful for any assistance :)

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue. Here's a test project: https://github.com/Egorand/wire-tastes

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the protos are in `src/main/proto`. Otherwise the plugin won't detect it. If moving it around is a problem, you can specify the path as an option in the `kotlin {}` configuration.

Comment: Yes the location of the proto files is ok, as if I take the import out, it works

Comment: Check the test project github.com/Egorand/wire-tastes

Comment: this is interesting... I am getting the same issue with your test project. So it looks like something with my environment? I am using android studio.. @oldergod

Comment: an update. I suspect an issue with windows path. I can get the imports to work if I place the tastes.proto file in the *src/main/proto* folder instead of *src/main/proto/testing/tastes* folder. I have tried adding the *tastes* directory to protoPath in gradle options, but all I get when I do this is *Collection contains no element matching the predicat* error. BTW using protoPath with a empty folder location seems the only way to compile (still get *unable to resolve 1 imports* issue though :( )but then get  Cannot find an example of how proto needs be structured.